# JProfiler is not able to detect any local running jvm, As I want to profile a java standalone application

Tags: jprofiler

JProfiler is not able to detect any local running jvm. Thinking of user access issue, I have started the java services with the same logged-in user on server but still no luck. Some help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: What JProfiler version do you use?

Comment: JProfiler 7.7.2.

Comment: JProfiler 10 has much better capabilities for discovering locally running services on Windows.

Comment: The problem is we have License sever of older version, which is not allowing new version Jprofiler to connect. We are using JProfiler Floating license.

Comment: You can try with the evaluation version.